# Translation of keywords algorithm2e

Tags: languages, algorithm2e

I would like to use `algorithm2e` with translated keywords option (e.g. `frenchkw`), which should be working according to the documentation, but it doesn't do nothing for me.

```
\usepackage[vlined, lined, french, frenchkw]{algorithm2e}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
    \While{not at end of this document}{
        read current\;
        \eIf{understand}{
            go to next section\;
            current section becomes this one\;
        }{
        go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
```

Result, notice how Algorithm caption is correctly translated, but keywords are not.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specify that you'll be using only `onelanguage` for this to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[vlined, french, onelanguage]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

While [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) does provide options for the use of different languages, without `onelanguage` it requires the user to specify different inputs for these. So, instead of `\KwData` - an `english`/default definition - one would need use `\Donnees` - the `french` definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[vlined, french]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \Donnees{this text}
  \Res{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \Tq{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eSi{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. Documentation should be more clear about this.